# XML Validation > Showing new elements for specific enumeration value

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I want to create a schema that enforces content validation across dependent elements.  If the contents of the first element is "ApplicationY", then the next element must be visible and mandatory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Instructions">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="Applications" >
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Application" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ApplicationName">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                          <xs:enumeration value="ApplicationX"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="ApplicationY"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="ApplicationZ"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="NextElementOnlyForApplicationY">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                          <xs:enumeration value="Yes"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="No"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Schemas cannot do this.  Schemas can do two things:

1. Ensure the existence of certain elements or attributes within other elements
2. Ensure that the contents of any element is valid within its own context

**A schema cannot enforce a rule for an element *contingent on the contents of another element*.**

What you can do is create an abstract base element, `Application`, which has more specific elements (such as `ApplicationY`) substituting for them.  The more specific elements can require additional sub-elements or attributes.

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="http://mynamespace" targetNamespace="http://mynamespace">
    <xs:element name="Instructions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Applications" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="my:Application" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Application" abstract="true" />
    <xs:element name="ApplicationX" substitutionGroup="my:Application" />
    <xs:element name="ApplicationY" substitutionGroup="my:Application">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ElementForApplicationY">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Yes"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="No"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ApplicationZ" substitutionGroup="my:Application" />

</xs:schema>
```

Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my:Instructions xmlns:my="http://mynamespace">
    <Applications>
        <my:ApplicationX />
        <my:ApplicationY>
            <ElementForApplicationY>Yes</ElementForApplicationY>
        </my:ApplicationY>
        <my:ApplicationZ />
    </Applications>
</my:Instructions>
```

Note that the use of substitution group requires the elements to be schema-level elements, not inner ones.  This means you need to define a namespace.